# Combine image targets and object targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

I'm am currently working on an AR personal project and I need some guidance.

I am trying to augment a physical sphere on which I have placed markers at different points on the sphere. These markers represent the different continents on the globe.

So in my setup, I will have a physical sphere with 5 markers on its surface and I want to have a Virtual sphere with continent names in AR. I'm using hololens for my AR experience and I'm building my AR app using unity and Vuforia.

I've been making research on how to do this and I saw that I can use an object scanner provided by Vuforia to scan my 3D model and save it in my data base which I'll then load to unity. Create image markers and overlay text (continent name) on it to be used in my app.

1.My concern is, how do I have my sphere and the continent name appearing at once? Since I'll have 5 markers for 5 continents, I want a sphere with these 5 continents names appearing on it surface based on the location of the markers on my actual physical sphere.

2.Also, I wish to have my virtual sphere rotate as I rotate my physical sphere,( haven't found anything on this yet).

In summary, I'll have 5 image target and one object target( using object scan in Vuforia)in my database. I'll overlay a virtual 3d sphere on my object target and text on the 5 image target ( multiple markers in Vuforia) but how can I have these individuals text appear on the surface of my virtual sphere. The sphere will always be present in our scene but the continent name will only appear once it recognises an image target if it appears on our scene as we rotate our physical sphere.

3. Any library, sample project or link were I could read more on how to implement this will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of high level pointers. You do not have to use Vuforia ImageTargets, these are made to detect planar images and might not work too well on a sphere (due to the curvature).

Also note that Object Target feature (and the object scanner) are deprecated. These have been replaced by scanned Model Target (see here https://library.vuforia.com/model-targets/how-create-model-targets-3d-scans)

In summary you need to scan you object and create a Model Target and then you can use Unity to author the experience an position your labels in the ModelTarget coordinate system. Vuforia will do the rest, track the object and make sure that the labels look anchored to the real object.

Here is a recent video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW3iLmn7IG8

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I followed that  tutorial but my vuforia app does not recognise my 3d model. It's a half white sphere(with some holes). From the documentation, it is not advice to use symmetric 3D objects like cubes, cylinders, spheres etc but I had a hard requirement to use a sphere... but in my case, a half sphere....

Comment: A half-sphere might work ok as long as it has some features (e.g., texture) to differentiate different views.